# After changes plymouth theme ubuntu dont boot

Tags: boot, 13.10, lightdm, plymouth

After I changed plymouth theme i cant boot up my pc. plymout show but after few second screen go off. I tried pres CTRL + ALT + 1 and CTRL + ALT + 7 but after that screen turn on but i can see only plymouth animation . Can someone please help me to fix it.

Comment: Try to log in and do `plymouth --quit` blindly.

Comment: Does Ctrl - Alt - F2 work? *(not straight away, but after a bit)*

Comment: Tried seems like no change. So I still se only an infinity plymout animation and no LightDM

Comment: yes CTRL ALT F 1/2/3/4 ... work